# How to set 12 pt font size, 10 pt line spacing, and 20 pica column width in IEEEtran document class?

Tags: line-spacing, column-width

I am trying to edit a manuscript of IEEEtran journal class by using Times Roman font, 12 pt font size, 10 pt line spacing, and 20 pica column width. I have been able to set the 12 pt font size with the following command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
```

However, I'm being unable to adjust the 10 pt line spacing and 20 pica column width. Can anyone please suggest me an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "10 pt line spacing". For instance, to you use the term to denote *additional* line spacing above and beyond the nominal font size of 12pt, for a *total* distance of 22pt between successive lines? Please advise.

Comment: I have the same issue using word file, I am formatting for IEEE communication magazine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you can use this at the preamble of your file. I used this during my submission, and it worked:

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran} % 12 pt font size
\usepackage{mathptmx} %\usepackage{times}% Times Roman font
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.7184} %\linespread{.7184} % both give 10 pt 
line spacing
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr (3.38338471in -1in/16)*2 + 3in/8\relax} % 
these two lines column widths
\setlength\columnsep{\dimexpr 3in/8\relax}
```